# How to link two Sharepoint Online list together?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, flow

I have the following table "New" and "Invoice Test". 
"New" list is essentially a PO List.

So, the current process is, I input company, title, amount and status in the "New" list. Then, I populate the Invoice Test list where PO1 is a lookup column from "New" list. 
I would like the "New" list to automatically populate the IN # matching the data from Invoice Test list. 
If the items match one to one I could run ms flow to solve this issue but I am currently stuck on the first item on "New" list (Title = a). 
Title "a" amount is $2000 with two invoices in Invoice Test list, a11 and a19. 
I can't seem to find a way to autopopulate two things on the same column using ms flow or any other methods that I could think of.

[image: "New" is essentially a PO list]

[image: Invoice Test List]

If you have any ideas in solving this issue, please help. 
I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: can't the IN# field be updated with two values separated by a semicolon? like "a11;a19" in the case of the first row?

Comment: IN # is lookup column and IN Number is a text column. I try to mess around with MS flow. The information on IN# is incorrect. But I will give semicolon a try, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If IN# is a lookup column, there is a checkbox in the lookup column settings, that says "Allow multiple values", which could accept more than one value in your case.

Or make IN# a single column text and have multi-values separated with a semicolon.

Comment: Sure. No problem :)